# Why is numpy's cumsum so much faster than manual C++'s loop?

Tags: c++, numpy, pybind11

I am trying to understand why is numpy's [cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) function so much faster than a manual c++ loop. I am using pybind to provide mapping from C++'s code to python.

Numbers first:

```py
[nav] In [24]: x = np.arange(100_000, dtype=np.float32)

[nav] In [25]: %timeit np.cumsum(x)
295 µs ± 34.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

[ins] In [26]: %timeit derived.cumsum(x)
9.26 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now how is `derived.cumsum(x)` obtained?

```cpp
template <typename Sequence,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<Sequence&&>>>
inline py::array_t<typename Sequence::value_type> as_pyarray(Sequence&& seq) {
  auto size = seq.size();
  auto data = seq.data();
  auto seq_ptr = std::make_unique<Sequence>(std::move(seq));
  auto capsule = py::capsule(seq_ptr.get(), [](void* p) {
    std::unique_ptr<Sequence>(reinterpret_cast<Sequence*>(p));
  });
  seq_ptr.release();
  return py::array(size, data, capsule);
}

std::vector<float> cumsum(const std::vector<float>& nums) {
  std::vector<float> result(nums.size());
  float sum = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
    sum += nums[i];
    result[i] = sum;
  }
  return result;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(derived, m) {
  m.def("cumsum", [](const std::vector<float>& nums) {
    auto result = cumsum(nums);
    return as_pyarray(std::move(result));
  });
}
```

`as_pyarray` was obtained from [this](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1042) pybind issue which ensures zero copy when interacting between python and c++.

Note that C++ code was compiled with `-O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC`.

Comment: Also, evaluating `nums.size()` for each iteration of the loop seems inefficient. Try assigning it to a `size_t` variable before the loop and using that in your test.

Comment: I don't know much about Python, so can't say: Does python use single-precision `float` data? In C++, on some platforms, storing and reading such `float` data is rather slower than the same operations on `double` data.

Comment: What exactly is that lambda supposed to accomplish, by constructing a unique_ptr, and then immediately destroying it? That does not make any sense.

Comment: *a manual c++ loop* -- To be honest, maybe that is the answer to your question.  Maybe the authors of the numpy version do things differently or more efficiently than your manual loop.  It may have nothing to do with the language used.

Comment: @AdrianMole Compilers are able to hoist `nums.size()` call outside the loop (apart from uint8 case where char* can alias and compiler can't reason that you are changing the size as you are iterating). However, I did try moving that to a temporary variable outside, and it didn't make any difference to the final numbers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is not immediately destroying it. it is calling `release` which says that ownership is done by someone else now. the linked pybind issue has more details.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Right. The intent of this question is to figure out what the numpy authors are doing special, and if a manual c++ loop can be transformed into that using compiler optimizations.

Comment: @skgbanga - I do not see the closure calling `release` anywhere. `release` is not getting called inside the closure but only ***after*** `py:capsule` returns, so constructing the `unique_ptr` inside the closure appears to accomplish absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever, so it gets destroyed immediately after construction. Not sure what that's supposed to do.

Comment: I don't know if it will be faster but you could use the standard library [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) algorithm instead of that `for` loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The lambda is presumably called when Python decides the array object is unreachable and GCs it. Then the destruction of the temporary `std::unique_ptr` during the lambda destroys and frees the `Sequence` at `p`. It could have been written with `delete reinterpret_cast<Sequence*>(p);`, but the comment in the Github thread the code is sourced from says that this version was written to avoid explicit `new`/`delete` (which I don't think is useful/should be done here... but whatever).

Comment: I tried exactly your algorithm in Numba (simple loop), it is about 3 times faster than np.cumsum (87µs, vs. 264µs). There must be something wrong with your wrapper.

Comment: @max9111 Thanks for posting that. Once you checked that, I also added timestamps in c++ code, and verified that c++ code itself is much faster and the problem must be with the glue code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the argument of cumsum. `const std::vector<float>&` is still doing a rather expensive copy. Directly taking `py::array_t<float>` as an argument resolves this issue.

More details are present at: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1042